# Benutzung von Anführungszeichen nach "namens"

Tags: typography

Momentan grüble ich über die Benutzung von Anführungszeichen im Zusammenhang mit "namens" bei der Bezeichnung von Gegenständen.

Ein Beispielsatz:
Der Rover namens "Perseverance" kommt 2021 am Mars an.

**Sind die Anführungszeichen bei dem Namen des Rovers nötig?**

Macht es einen Unterschied, ob dort "ein Rover" statt "der Rover" steht?

Bei der Suche im Internet bin ich auf die Regel gestoßen, dass Eigennamen so geschrieben werden, wie sie eben sind.

Ein Beispielsatz:
Gestern besuchte ich die Milchbar in Berlin.

Da die Bezeichnung "Milchbar" eine Art Eigenname ist, muss diese nicht in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden. Dies würde bedeuten, dass im Beispielsatz "Der Rover Perseverance kommt 2021 am Mars an." der Name des Rovers nicht in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden muss. Das "namens" verwirrt mich jetzt.

Comment: Woher stammt denn das Rover-Beispiel? Macht die Quelle den Eindruck, von deutschen Muttersprachlern geschrieben worden zu sein?

Comment: Es stammt von mir. Ich schreibe den Satz in einer Arbeit und bin mir nicht sicher, ob Anführungszeichen nötig sind.

Comment: bei Anführungszeichen frag ich mich immer, wen zitierst du da eigentlich? Ansonsten sieht es auch aus wie sogenannte "scarequotes" (s. Urbandictionay)

Comment: @vectory: Scarequotes drücken Skepsis, Ablehnung oder Ironie aus. Sie bedeuten, dass sich der Autor von dem in Anführungszeichen gesetzten Begriff distanzieren will. (z.B.: *Sechs selbsternannte "Sittenwächter" wurden von der Polizei festgenommen.*) Wenn ich aber zum Beispiel etwas über die korrekte Verwendung des Wortes "namens" schreibe, darf ich dieses Wort in Anführungszeichen setzen, obwohl ich dabei niemanden zitiere, und obwohl es sich hier um keine Scarequotes handelt. Details dazu stehen am Ende [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62415/1487).

Comment: Das Beispiel mit der Milchbar könnte allerdings durch Anführungszeichen deutlischer werden: War das eine bestimmte Gaststätte, die den Namen "Milchbar" trägt? Oder eine - bzw. dem Satz nach die einzige - Berliner Gaststätte, die sich auf Milchgetränke spezialisert hat (aber vielleicht "Zur glücklichen Kuh" heißt)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "Milchbar" ist der Name einer bestimmten Gaststätte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mir ist keine Regel bekannt, wonach der Name, auf den sich das Adverb *»namens«* bezieht, in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden müsse. Hier ein paar Beispiele aus dem wirklichen Leben:

- [Ein Fisch namens Wanda](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Fisch_namens_Wanda)
- [Ein Hund namens Wanda](https://www.ksta.de/ein-hund-namens-wanda-13465714?cb=1609537583925)
- [Ein Hund namens Riley](https://www.akademisches-graz.at/ein-hund-namens-riley/)
- [Ein Hund namens Dollar](https://www.mdw.ac.at/maxreinhardtseminar/ein-hund-namens-dollar/)
- [Ein Hund namens Gertrude](https://blog.the-british-shop.at/page/view/2020/01/ein-hund-namens-gertrude-beliebte-namen-fuers-haustier/)
- [Ein Beagle namens Daria](https://amalthea.at/produkt/ein-beagle-namens-daria/)
- [Eine Spinne namens Obama](https://kurier.at/wissen/prominente-namensgeber-fuer-15-neue-spinnenarten/288.502.043)
- [Ein Mann namens Ove](https://www.fischerverlage.de/buch/fredrik-backman-ein-mann-namens-ove-9783596521111)
- [Ein Junge namens Weihnacht](https://www.dtv.de/buch/matt-haig-ein-junge-namens-weihnacht-28088/)
- [Ein Mädchen namens Willow](https://www.thalia.at/shop/home/artikeldetails/ID145729389.html)
- [Ein Mädchen namens Livia](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2012/02/06/ein-madchen-namens-livia/)

Das kann man ergänzen um Beispiel aus Wörterbüchern:

- [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/namens_genannt)

  - ein Mann namens Maier
- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/namens)

  - Die Inselgruppe namens Feuerland
  - ein Roßhändler, namens Michael Kohlhaas
  - ein Dorf namens Berlin
  - Ein Patrizier namens Albinus
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/namens)

  - ein Mann namens Kirchner
  - ein Roßhändler, namens Michael Kohlhaas
  - ein Dorf namens Gries
- [Uni Leipzip](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=namens)
  Der Korpus der Uni Leipzig enthält 8846 Beispiele. Ich habe mir nur die ersten 200 Beispiele angesehen, darunter war kein einziges mit Anführungszeichen.

Es gibt aber auch Gegenbeispiele, allerdings konnte ich nur zwei finden:

- [Ein Baby namens "Eclipse"](https://www.vol.at/ein-baby-namens-eclipse/5422591)
- [Ein Hund namens "Adolf"](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000119528008/ein-hund-namens-adolf-rechtsextreme-umtriebe-bei-polizei-aufgedeckt)

Es steht also ungefähr 9000 : 2 für die Version ohne Anführungszeichen.

---

**Heißt das, dass die Anführungszeichen falsch sind?**

Nicht unbedingt. In manchen Fällen kann das korrekt sein.

Der Rechtschreibrat ist das einzige amtliche Gremium, dass über die Schreibweise der deutschen Sprache entscheidet. Die aktuelle Version des Regelverzeichnisses stammt aus dem Jahr 2018 und kann [als PDF-Dokument heruntergeladen werden](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf).

Der Abschnitt E behandelt die Zeichensetzung, darin das Kapitel 3 die Anführungszeichen. Eine der vielen Regeln über Anführungszeichen ist dieser Paragraph:

> **§ 94** Mit Anführungszeichen kann man Wörter oder Teile innerhalb eines Textes hervorheben und in bestimmten Fällen deutlich machen, dass man zu ihrer Verwendung Stellung nimmt, sich auf sie bezieht.

Es folgen Erläuterungen welche Konstellationen das betrifft, darunter:

> **(3)** Wörter oder Wortgruppen, über die man eine Aussage machen will:
> *Das Wort „fälisch“ ist gebildet in Anlehnung an West„falen“. Der Begriff „Existenzialismus“ wird heute vielfältig verwendet. Alle seine Freunde nannten ihn „Dickerchen“. Die Präposition „ohne“ verlangt den Akkusativ.*

Wenn du also das Wort *»Perseverance«* hervorheben und eine Aussage über das Wort (nicht über die Sache, die mit dem Wort bezeichnet wird) machen willst, so wie ich es hier in diesem Satz mache, dann kannst du Anführungszeichen verwenden (du musst nicht). Wenn du aber nur darüber schreibst, dass ein Rover namens Perseverance auf dem Mars ankommen wird, ohne näher auf diesen Namen einzugehen, dann lass die Anführungszeichen lieber weg.

Comment: Die Sache verhält sich doch bei "heißen" auch gleich, oder? 
Beispielsatz: Der Flugkörper hieß Sputnik 1. 
Dabei muss "Sputnik 1" ebenfalls NICHT in Anführungszeichen geschrieben werden, da auf die Bezeichnung an sich ja nicht eingegangen wird, oder?

Comment: @Meiki: Du hast recht. Aber das gilt nicht nur für die beiden Wörter *»namens«* und *»heißen«,* sondern für **alle** deutschen Wörter die in der Nähe von Namen stehen. Die Tatsache, dass ein Begriff ein Name ist, ist niemals ein Grund dafür, diesen Namen in Anführungszeichen zu setzen, egal mit welchen Wörtern man Bezug darauf nimmt. (Es kann aber andere Gründe für die Verwendung von Anführungszeichen geben.)

Answer (score 1):

Anführungsstriche werden in solchem Kontext benutzt, um einen Namen von einer wirklichen Bedeutung zu unterscheiden. Perseverance ist kein deutsches Wort, so dass eine Verwechslung nicht zu erwarten ist. Man kann wahrscheinlich in jedem Kontext auf Anführungsstrichel verzichten.

Ein prominentes Gegenbeispiel ist Der Führer vs. Der "Führer".